# Continuous map on compact Hausdorff spaces is closed

Tags: general-topology, continuity, compactness, separation-axioms, closed-map

If $(X,\tau)$ and $(Y,\tau_1)$ are compact Hausdorff spaces and $f:(X,\tau) \rightarrow (Y,\tau_1)$ is a continuous mapping, prove that $f$ is a closed mapping.

My outline of the proof is that Let $A \in Y$ be a closed set, then $f^{-1}(A)$ is closed in X since $f$ is continuous. I have to show that $f(f^{-1}(A)) = A$ and therefore $f$ is close mapping.

Am I doing the right thing?

Comment: No. You have to pick a closed $C \subset X$, and show that $f(C)$ is closed in $Y$.

Answer (score 3):

You have to show that if $A\subseteq X$ is closed, then $f(A)\subseteq Y$ is closed. Because $X$ is compact, the closed set $A\subseteq X$ is compact. Since $f$ is continuous, $f(A)$ is compact in $Y$. Since $Y$ is Hausdorff and $f(A)$ is compact in $Y$, then $f(A)$ is closed in $Y$.

I am using these two standard results:

> **Theorem:** A closed subset of a compact topological space is compact.
>
> **Thoorem:** A compact subset of a Hausdorff topological space is closed.

Comment: Don't we need $f$ to be surjective to say that $f(A)$ is compact in $Y$?

Comment: @user1292919 No, the image of a compact subset by a continuous map is always compact.

Comment: Ok! that makes my life easier..