# Product of a quotient space and the unit interval

Tags: general-topology

If $X$ is a topological space and $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $X$, I want to show that 
$\tau: X \times I \to (X/{\sim}) \times I, \; (x,t) \mapsto (\pi(x),t)$ (where $I =[0,1]$ and $\pi: X \to X/{\sim}$ is the quotient map) is an identification. 
Obviously, $\tau$ is continuous. But how do I prove that $\tau^{-1}(U)$ is open iff $U$ is open? So far all of my attempts have failed since $\pi$ can't be assumed to be an open map.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: The definition of the topology on the quotient space is $\{U|\pi^{-1}(U)$ is open$\}$. So $\pi$ is open from definition.

Comment: @ShakedBader not all quotient maps are open

Comment: As I recall this is kind of delicate. Its theorem 20.1 in munkres "elements of algebraic topology."  If you dont have that book I can try to give you a screenshot of the proof.  It holds more generally if $I$ is replaced with a locally compact hausdorff space.

Comment: @Tim kinsella Thank you. I shall have a look at it later!

Comment: @ShakedBader See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/655797/example-of-quotient-mapping-that-is-not-open

Comment: Note the typographical difference between $X/\sim$ and $X/{\sim}.$ Binary operation symbols have a certain amount of space before and after them (present in $5+3$ but absent in $+3$ or in $5+$) but in $X/{\sim}$ that space shouldn't be there because the symbol isn't being used in that way. But when nothing is before or after it, then those spaces are not there. In other words, code this as X/{\sim}. $\qquad$

Comment: What is an _identification_? Is it a synonym for a _quotient map_?

Comment: @Peter Elias Essentially yes. A continous surjection $f: X \to Y$ is an identification if $U \subseteq Y$ is open iff $f^{-1}(U)$ is open.